# Bluemix - Error 500 while creating an instance of Sendgrid service

Tags: ibm-cloud, sendgrid

For three days I try to create an instance of the service SendGrid. Each time i get this error message :

```
Service broker error: {"description"=>"Error 500 received from broker url https://bluemix-eu-gb.marketplace.ibmcloud.com/api/custom/cloudfoundry/v2/service_instances/XXXX"}
```

If someone has an idea of the problem...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We are not aware of any ongoing issue as you can see on the [Bluemix Status Page](https://status.ng.bluemix.net). I've just tried to create a new instance of [Sendgrid](https://new-console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/catalog/services/sendgrid/) ("Bronze Package" Plan) using both the [Classic UI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net) and the ["New Experience" UI](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net). I suggest you to try again, it should work.

If the problem persists it could be related to your org and I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI. After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is still persisting, we made a support request as you suggested.